# Ordinal arithmetic $(\omega+1) \cdot \omega$ and $\omega \cdot (\omega +1)$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Here is where I am so far:
 $(\omega+1) \cdot \omega = \sup\{(\omega +1) \cdot n, n \in \omega\} = \omega^2$

and $\omega \cdot (\omega +1) = \omega \cdot \omega + \omega = \omega^2 + \omega$

Hence 
$((\omega+1) \cdot \omega) \in (\omega \cdot (\omega +1))$

Is this true? (I am least sure about the first line..)

Comment: Yes, it’s correct.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha should support ordinal arithmetic.

Comment: Great, thanks!! Didn't know I could Wolfram it. :)

Comment: @columbus8myhw: Should, or does?

Comment: …Should. @Andrew

Comment: Correct, but the expression $((\omega+1)\cdot\omega)\in(\omega\cdot(\omega+1))$ makes my skin crawl. Why don't you just write $(\omega+1)\omega\lt\omega(\omega+1)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're uncertain about the first line, why not expand it further? What is $(\omega+1)\cdot n$?

Quick calculation will show you that it is $\omega\cdot n+1$, and intuitively it's stacking $n$ copies of $\omega+1$ one after another, so the first $n-1$ copies "swallow" the $+1$, and you are left with $\omega\cdot n+1$.

So now what is $\sup\{\omega\cdot n+1\mid n\in\omega\}$? It is $\omega^2$, as you wrote.

Comment: Thank you for the verification!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Why isn't it $\omega^2+1$? I'm confused.

Comment: @Whyka: $\omega\cdot n+1<\omega\cdot(n+1)<\omega\cdot(n+1)+1<\ldots$. So the supremum is the same for both sequences.

Comment: @Whyka: It's easier to think about it as stacking copies of an order type one after another. If you stack a bunch of copies of $\omega\cdot n+1$, the $+1$ keeps getting "swallowed" into the next copies. So if the number of copies you stack has no last element, the $+1$ disappears.